# Ehcache & MultiThreading

Tags: java, multithreading, ehcache

Does ehcache support multi-threading by default or does it require any configuration changes?
On multi threading my application with Ehcache i found that the DB hit count is actually increasing i.e. there is no global cache available for all the threads despite the fact that my cache's are all Singletons. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may help answer your question, from [the FAQ](http://ehcache.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html):

> **Is it thread safe to modify Element values after retrieval from a Cache?**
>
> Remember that a value in a cache element is globally accessible from multiple threads. *It is inherently not thread safe to modify the value.* It is safer to retrieve a value, delete the cache element and then reinsert the value.

*(emphasis added by me)*

Comment: Another option is to look at the ehcache explicit locking API: http://ehcache.org/documentation/explicitlocking.html, since any discussion on ehcache and multithreading is perhaps incomplete without considering this aspect as well.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official documentation](http://www.ehcache.org/about/features.html) appears it is *specifically built and tested to run well under highly concurrent access*, as long as you do not modify `Element` from the multiple threads.

But, of course, this does not mean that using Ehcache makes other parts of your code thread safe. If you fetch the same value from multiple threads (using the same key), the instance may be shared and you need to know what you are doing before modifying it. Best seems to use immutable objects like strings as cached values.